# scraping data from google finance using php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data off google finance using php..I am trying to extract the usd to zar conversion rate from google finance site...There seems to be some sort of error in the regular expression i am using...could someone please suggest me the correct method...Below is my code...

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance?q=USDZAR');
echo $page;
preg_match("/<span class=\"bld\".*span>/", $page, $conversion_rate);
print_r($conversion_rate);

?>
```

I am getting am empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a DOM parser and XPath to select the content of that span tag. Like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=USDZAR';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$span = $selector->query('//span[@class="bld"]')->item(0);

var_dump($span->nodeValue);
```

Comment: thanks hek2mgl....could you pleaese explain to me what i was doing wrong in my code???

Comment: You are using regexes to extract content from HTML. :)

Comment: Btw, the problem is that Google delivers invalid HTML.. The class attribute value is missing the `"` double quotes in that span.

Comment: cool :) :) thanks bud :)...btw your method is better than mine and the code is clean too..really appreciate your help :)

Comment: No problem. Nice that we stumbled upon a real world scenario where a regex made problems. Have a look at XPath. You can select *everything* out of XML/HTML documents.